# python: how to merge a list into clusters?

Tags: python, list, cluster-analysis

I have a list of tuples:

```
[(3,4), (18,27), (4,14)]
```

and need a code merging tuples which has repeated numbers, making another list where all list elements will only contain unique numbers. The list should be sorted by the length of the tuples, i.e.:

```
>>> MergeThat([(3,4), (18,27), (4,14)])
[(3,4,14), (18,27)]

>>> MergeThat([(1,3), (15,21), (1,10), (57,66), (76,85), (66,76)])
[(57,66,76,85), (1,3,10), (15,21)]
```

I understand it's something similar to hierarchical clustering algorithms, which I've read about, but can't figure them out.

Is there a relatively simple code for a MergeThat() function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried hard to figure this out, but only after I tried the approach Ian's answer (thanks!) suggested I realized what the theoretical problem is: The input is a list of edges and defines a graph. We are looking for the strongly connected components of this graph. It's simple as that.

While you can [do this efficiently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm), there is actually no reason to implement this yourself! Just import a [good graph library](https://networkx.org/):

```
import networkx as nx

# one of your examples
g1 = nx.Graph([(1,3), (15,21), (1,10), (57,66), (76,85), (66,76)])
print nx.connected_components(g1) # [[57, 66, 76, 85], [1, 10, 3], [21, 15]]

# my own test case
g2 =  nx.Graph([(1,2),(2,10), (20,3), (3,4), (4,10)])
print nx.connected_components(g2) # [[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20]]
```

Comment: thank you. Although I accepted inspectorG4dget's answer, this method is obviously the fastest one.

Comment: huge thanks again for pointing me into the networkx library! It's so great.

Answer (score 4):

```
import itertools

def merge_it(lot):
    merged = [ set(x) for x in lot ] # operate on sets only
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        finished = True
        for a, b in itertools.combinations(merged, 2):
            if a & b:
                # we merged in this iteration, we may have to do one more
                finished = False
                if a in merged: merged.remove(a)
                if b in merged: merged.remove(b)    
                merged.append(a.union(b))
                break # don't inflate 'merged' with intermediate results
    return merged

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print merge_it( [(3,4), (18,27), (4,14)] )
    # => [set([18, 27]), set([3, 4, 14])]

    print merge_it( [(1,3), (15,21), (1,10), (57,66), (76,85), (66,76)] )
    # => [set([21, 15]), set([1, 10, 3]), set([57, 66, 76, 85])]

    print merge_it( [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,9)] )
    # => [set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9])]
```

Here's a snippet (including doctests): http://gist.github.com/586252

Comment: Itertools makes the Swiss Army Knife look limited. O_o

Comment: Possibly stupid question: Why do you do `merged.append(set([ x for x in chain.from_iterable( (a, b) ) ]))` instead of `merged.append(a + b)`?  Or maybe `merged.append(set(chain.from_iterable( (a, b) ))`?

Comment: Because `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'`; but you're right a `union` will do. Thanks.

Comment: For the last example I'm getting an error: 
>>> print merge_it( [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,9)] )

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#68>", line 1, in <module>
      print merge_it( [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,9)] )
    File "<pyshell#62>", line 6, in merge_it
      for a, b in combinations(merged, 2):
  ValueError: r cannot be bigger than the iterable

Comment: I adjusted the code since I posted it; have you tried the current version? It works fine for me with python 2.6+.

Comment: This is not criticism, but I have the **feeling** that this should be doable in n or nlogn, not n**2. I can't see it though :/ Maybe someone can elaborate what's behind this? :-)

Comment: @The MYYN: I'm also using 2.6, and getting this error: "r cannot be bigger than the iterable"

Answer (score 1):

```
def collapse(L):
    """ The input L is a list that contains tuples of various sizes.
        If any tuples have shared elements, 
        exactly one instance of the shared and unshared elements are merged into the first tuple with a shared element.
        This function returns a new list that contain merged tuples and an int that represents how many merges were performed."""
    answer = []
    merges = 0
    seen = []   # a list of all the numbers that we've seen so far
    for t in L:
        tAdded = False
        for num in t:
            pleaseMerge = True
            if num in seen and pleaseMerge:
                answer += merge(t, answer)
                merges += 1
                pleaseMerge = False
                tAdded= True
            else:
                seen.append(num)
        if not tAdded:
            answer.append(t)

    return (answer, merges)

def merge(t, L):
    """ The input L is a list that contains tuples of various sizes.
        The input t is a tuple that contains an element that is contained in another tuple in L.
        Return a new list that is similar to L but contains the new elements in t added to the tuple with which t has a common element."""
    answer = []
    while L:
        tup = L[0]
        tupAdded = False
        for i in tup:
            if i in t:
                try:
                    L.remove(tup)
                    newTup = set(tup)
                    for i in t:
                        newTup.add(i)
                    answer.append(tuple(newTup))
                    tupAdded = True
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        if not tupAdded:
            L.remove(tup)
            answer.append(tup)
    return answer

def sortByLength(L):
    """ L is a list of n-tuples, where n>0.
        This function will return a list with the same contents as L 
        except that the tuples are sorted in non-ascending order by length"""

    lengths = {}
    for t in L:
        if len(t) in lengths.keys():
            lengths[len(t)].append(t)
        else:
            lengths[len(t)] = [(t)]

    l = lengths.keys()[:]
    l.sort(reverse=True)

    answer = []
    for i in l:
        answer += lengths[i]
    return answer

def MergeThat(L):
    answer, merges = collapse(L)
    while merges:
        answer, merges = collapse(answer)
    return sortByLength(answer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'starting'
    print MergeThat([(3,4), (18,27), (4,14)])
    # [(3, 4, 14), (18, 27)]
    print MergeThat([(1,3), (15,21), (1,10), (57,66), (76,85), (66,76)])
    # [(57, 66, 76, 85), (1, 10, 3), (15, 21)]
```

Comment: What would be the way to sort the final list by the length of tuples (it's in the initial post)? I.e., print MergeThat([(1,3), (15,21), (1,10), (57,66), (76,85), (66,76)]) should return [(57, 66, 76, 85), (1, 10, 3), (15, 21)].

Comment: @user63505: I have added a new function called sortByLength to add this functionality. I have also added a line in MergeThat to implement this functionality. However, this handles sorting of equal-length-tuples arbitrarily. If there's any rule(s) by which you'd like this to be handled, I can try to implement that too. Hope This Helps

Comment: You can replace sortByLength(L) with `sorted(L, key=len, reverse=True)`

Comment: Thank you @THC4k. I did not know this. This should be /very/ helpfulf for the future

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that doesn't use `itertools` and takes a different, slightly more verbose, approach. The tricky bit of this solution is the merging of cluster sets when `t0 in index and t1 in index`.

```
import doctest

def MergeThat(a):
    """ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744048/python-how-to-merge-a-list-into-clusters

    >>> MergeThat([(3,4), (18,27), (4,14)])
    [(3, 4, 14), (18, 27)]
    >>> MergeThat([(1,3), (15,21), (1,10), (57,66), (76,85), (66,76)])
    [(57, 66, 76, 85), (1, 3, 10), (15, 21)]
    """
    index = {}
    for t0, t1 in a:
        if t0 not in index and t1 not in index:
            index[t0] = set()
            index[t1] = index[t0]
        elif t0 in index and t1 in index:
            index[t0] |= index[t1]
            oldt1 = index[t1]
            for x in index.keys():
                if index[x] is oldt1:
                    index[x] = index[t0]
        elif t0 not in index:
            index[t0] = index[t1]
        else:
            index[t1] = index[t0]
        assert index[t0] is index[t1]
        index[t0].add(t0)
        index[t0].add(t1)
    return sorted([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in set(map(frozenset, index.values()))], key=len, reverse=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code others have written will surely work, but here's another option, maybe simpler to understand and maybe less algorithmic complexity.

Keep a dictionary from numbers to the cluster (implemented as a python set) they're a member of. Also include that number in the corresponding set. Process an input pair either as:

1. Neither element is in the dictionary: create a new set, hook up dictionary links appropriately.
2. One or the other, but not both elements are in the dictionary: Add the yet-unseen element to the set of its brother, and add its dictionary link into the correct set.
3. Both elements are seen before, but in different sets: Take the union of the old sets and update all dictionary links to the new set.
4. You've seen both members before, and they're in the same set: Do nothing.

Afterward, simply collect the unique values from the dictionary and sort in descending order of size. This portion of the job is O(m log n) and thus will not dominate runtime.

This should work in a single pass. Writing the actual code is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That's precisely what my solution does.

Answer (score 0):

This is not efficient for huge lists.

```
def merge_that(lot):
   final_list = []
   while len(lot) >0 :
      temp_set = set(lot[0])
      deletable = [0]      #list of all tuples consumed by temp_set
      for i, tup2 in enumerate(lot[1:]):
         if tup2[0] in temp_set or tup2[1] in temp_set:
            deletable.append(i)
            temp_set = temp_set.union(tup2)
      for d in deletable:
         del lot[d]
      deletable = []
      # Some of the tuples consumed later might have missed their brothers
      # So, looping again after deleting the consumed tuples
      for i, tup2 in enumerate(lot):
         if tup2[0] in temp_set or tup2[1] in temp_set:
            deletable.append(i)
            temp_set = temp_set.union(tup2)
      for d in deletable:
         del lot[d]
      final_list.append(tuple(temp_set))
   return final_list
```

It looks ugly but works.